# What is this new /run filesystem?

Tags: linux, filesystems, directory-structure

I just ran `df -h` a minute ago and noticed a filesystem has been added that I'm not familiar with. Does anyone know why `/run` exists? Is this something that's 
been added by the kernel? By [Arch Linux](http://www.archlinux.org/)?

```
run              10M  236K  9.8M   3% /run
```

Comment: Related: See the Debian `/run` release goal document, which includes details about how the change applies to 7.0+.  http://wiki.debian.org/ReleaseGoals/RunDirectory

Comment: See here: https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s15.html

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Apparently, many tools (among them udev) will soon require a /run/ directory that is mounted early (as tmpfs). Arch developers introduced /run last month to prepare for this.

> The udev runtime data moved from /dev/.udev/ to /run/udev/. The
> /run mountpoint is supposed to be a tmpfs mounted during early boot,
> available and writable to for all tools at any time during bootup,
> it replaces /var/run/, which should become a symlink some day.
> [1]

There is more detail here: http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Linux-distributions-to-include-run-directory-1219006.html

[1] From [thread on the Arch Projects ML](http://mailman.archlinux.org/pipermail/arch-projects/2011-March/000517.html)

Comment: is it only for Arch or what ? `/run` will be add in RHEL/CentOs, Ubuntu ?

Comment: Do files get automatically deleted when the process stops running?

Comment: @Ian, if it's a tmpfs filesystem, then on reboot it will be emptied.
Your question: as I know, files would not be automatically deleted, rather process itself has to do proper cleanup.

Comment: @BulatM. tmpfs is explicitly RAM-backed (it will swap though if not all fits in RAM), so on power off everything in /run is lost by design, and no process has to go and clean up previous files.

Answer (score 53):

The `/run` directory is the companion directory to `/var/run`. Like for example `/bin` is the companion of `/usr/bin`.

That means that daemons like `systemd` and `udev`, which are started very early in the boot process - and perhaps before `/var/run` is available (i.e. mounted) - have with `/run` a standardized file system location available where they can store runtime information.

Like `/bin` contains important programs, which may be needed in the boot process before `/usr` is available (in case it is on its own filesystem).

The `/run` idea is a relatively new idea/standard.

Comment: Arch's `/var/run` directory is symlinked to `/run`.

Comment: Debian's `/var/run` is also symlinked to `/run`

Comment: So is Ubuntu 16.10's.

Comment: This answer is misleading. /run exists because /var/run was the wrong location, and most distros either symlink or bind mount them to each other. They are not intended to be separate directories; /run is the correct location, /var/run is kept around to support legacy software. See https://lwn.net/Articles/436012/ for the motivation behind it.

Comment: @MatthewSharp your comment is misleading. Did you even read the link you posted?

Comment: @maxschlepzig Yes I did. My comment was probably a bit non-specific, but it would help if you were more specific about what is misleading in my comment.