# What are /dev, /run and /run/shm and can I resize them?

Tags: filesystems, linux-mint, disk-usage

So, I recently created a 15GB partition for Linux Mint 14. I've been working on it for a while, and I got a Low Disk Space notification. I ran `df -h` and this is what I'm getting:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5        11G   11G  2.3M 100% /
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           751M  1.1M  750M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G  4.0M  1.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   16K  100M   1% /run/user
```

What are `/dev`, `/run`, and `/run/shm`, and can I resize them to be smaller and extend `/dev/sda5` to use that space instead?

Comment: I suspect you have a <~15,000,000,000B partition with a >~11*1024*1024*1024B filesystem. Post the output of `fdisk -l` and `df /` (without `-h`, to have precise numbers). Anyway, unless you've resized the partition or something, the filesystem uses all the space in the partition. `/run` and the others are not the same filesystem, they don't take up any space in the partition ([nor in RAM for that matter — only the ~5MB that's in use](http://askubuntu.com/questions/278918/shrink-the-size-of-tmpfs-folders/278920#278920)).

Comment: As Gilles wrote, only the "Filesystem" `/dev/sda5` directly occupies space on the harddrive. The other volumes are in the RAM disk (but they occupy only the used space). More details are also in my reply here: [Shrink or delete udev partition in Ubuntu?](http://superuser.com/q/675568/61370#675664)

Answer (score 7):

`/run` and `/run/shm` are temporary filesystems residing in RAM. See [What is this new filesystem /run?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13972/what-is-this-new-filesystem-run)

`/dev` is where [udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) manages the device nodes for the kernel.

Essentially, you can change the size of your `tmpfs` (it is set by default to use half your total RAM) but, looking at your overall disk usage, you have a more pressing space issue than resizing your temporary filesystem.

The [Arch Wiki fstab entry on tmpfs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab#tmpfs) has details on how to resize it by, for example, including a line in your `/etc/fstab`:

```
tmpfs   /tmp    tmpfs   nodev,nosuid,size=2G     0  0
```

Comment: So if the `/run` folders are coming from my RAM, does that mean `/` and `/dev` come from the allocated space? If so, that still only adds up to 13GB - any idea where the other 2GB go?

Comment: The `tmpfs` is the maximum size that *may* be used. Your filesystem may also be using space for [fsck to track files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18154/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-lostfound-folder-in-linux-and-unix)...

Comment: @h7u9i, it is your root filesystem that is full; ignore the others.

Answer (score 2):

Temporary increase tmpfs filesystem

1) Open /etc/fstab with vi or any text editor of your choice,

2) Locate the line of /dev/shm and use the tmpfs size option to specify your expected size,

e.g. 512MB:
tmpfs      /dev/shm      tmpfs   defaults,size=512m   0   0

e.g. 2GB:
tmpfs      /dev/shm      tmpfs   defaults,size=2g   0   0

mount -o remount /dev/shm