# what is the distinction between /media, /mnt and /run/mount?

Tags: gnome, directory-structure, fhs

In FHS-2.3, we have `/media` that holds mount points for removable media such as CD-ROMs and we have `/mnt` that holds temporarily mounted filesystems.

On the other hand, we have `/run/media` and `/run/mount`. For me, the CDs and USBs are mounted on /run/media.

I don't see any clear distinction between them(`/media`, `/mnt`, `/run/mount`) . What are their differences?

---

I have seen similar trend (mount on /run/media) in fedora 20 - GNOME 3.10.4 and ubuntu 14.04.1 (installed on virtual box) with GNOME 3.10.4. But when I plugged in a USB flash (with auto-mounter script) on a system with Centos 6 and GNOME 2.28.2 it was mounted on `/media`

Comment: The `/run/mount/` thing happens when you use some kind of auto-mounter script - it mounts the disk in a user-owned directory. `/media` and `/mnt` are root-owned usually - so there's that at least.

Comment: `udisks2` mounts to `/run/media` and the older `udisks` mounts to `/media`... See also [What is this new /run filesystem?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13972/what-is-this-new-run-filesystem)

Comment: Why would I mount anything in root? That would require applications and Terminal sudo to be able to write to the. Why not just use home? I'm mounting a folder from local network.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`FHS` v2.3 was released ten years ago. Some things have changed since then (including the introduction of `/run`<sup>1</sup>). About three years ago, the Linux Foundation decided to update the standard and [invited all interested parties](https://lists.linux-foundation.org/pipermail/fhs-discuss/2011-May/000001.html) to participate.
You can view the v. 3.0 drafts [here](http://www.linuxbase.org/betaspecs/fhs/) and the section that describes `/run` [here](http://www.linuxbase.org/betaspecs/fhs/fhs/ch03s15.html).
The distinction between `/media` and `/mnt` is pretty clear in the `FHS` (see *Purpose* and *Rationale*), so I won't go over it again. Same for the purpose of `/run` - see links.

The Gnome story is yet another thing. Gnome uses underneath an application called `udisks` (replaced later by `udisks2`) to automount drives/devices. For quite a long time, `udisks` default mounts were under `/media`. In 2012 the devs decide to move the mounts to [`/run/media`](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/udisks/commit/?id=aa02e5fc53efdeaf66047d2ad437ed543178965b) (i.e. a private directory). So the different behaviour you're experiencing there is caused by the different versions of `udisks` that each DE is using.

<sup>1: see

[What's this /run directory doing on my system and where does it come from ?](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2011-March/150031.html)

[What is this new /run filesystem ?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13972)</sup>

Comment: udisks link is already dead

Comment: and where should I map or mount NFS? In `/mnt`?

Answer (score 2):

FHS states that `/media` is for users and `/mnt` is for admins. Furthermore, it forbids adding user mounts into `/mnt` since that was a common practice before `/media` was created.

`/run` is the replacement for `/var/run`. Those directories are for changes made to the system since boot and should be cleared on each boot. Since mountable media is something that gets cleared on boots some utilities use `/run`.

It would be nice if a future FHS addresses these differences by mandating that media is moved to `/run` or that media is not put in `/run`.  I'm hitting these on different systems too and I'll have to code around it.

Details at: http://www.linuxbase.org/betaspecs/fhs/fhs.html#mediaMountPoint