# How can I decrypt a file to use in another command without writing decrypted file to disk?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I have a command (`ansible-vault decrypt`) that decrypts a file and writes it out. I can write it out to a file or to `-`/`stdout`.

I would then like to use this decrypted file (a private key) with another command that expects an argument like `mycommand --key-file <path to file>`.

My current script runs `ansible-vault decrypt --output mykey.key` to write the decrypted file to disk, then `mycommand --key-file mykey.key`, and finally deleting it with `rm mykey.key`.

Is there a way to somehow not write the decrypted file to disk at all, and still have `mycommand` be able to access it as if it was a file?

I can't pipe to the second command, because it doesn't read the key from stdin at all. The only thing I could think of is to create a ramdisk before running the commands, writing the key there, and unmounting the ramdisk once all commands have run which (I think) would make the decrypted key disappear without a trace.

Comment: Can the `ansible-vault decrypt` command write to standard output or does it require a file?

Comment: Temporary filesystems (`tmpfs`) are run in RAM ... and SWAP - which might be your problem. Nevertheless, read permissions work the same as on the hard disk, so I feel like you want to target a security problem in the wrong manner. What is your target and what do you fear?

Comment: Not the answer to the question, just a note. The best way to delete sensitive data is to `shred` it first. Otherwise it can still be recovered from the HD

Answer (score 3):

If the command expects a file name, but doesn't care about the file type, you can pass the data through a pipe and specify `/dev/stdin` as the file name. `/dev/stdin` refers to the standard input.

```
ansible-vault decrypt | mycommand --key-file /dev/stdin
```

This won't work if `mycommand` doesn't accept a pipe (which usually happens if the program requires the file to be seekable). In that case, you will need to write the key to a temporary file.

Most Linux systems (and many other Unix variants) do have an in-memory filesystem out of the box. Where this filesystem is mounted and what permissions are required to use it depends on the distribution. Modern Linux systems have a [tmpfs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmpfs) filesystem mounted at several locations, including [`/run`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13972/what-is-this-new-run-filesystem). Normally every user gets a directory `/run/user/1234` at login time where 1234 is their user ID. Many services create their own directory under `/run`, and `/var/run` is usually a symbolic link to `/run`. Check what is available on your system with `df -t tmpfs`.

Note that data written to a temporary filesystem can end up in swap. So can the content of memory. If the theft of your hard disk is a threat that you want to defend against, you must encrypt your swap. If you don't use hibernation, you can use a random key for the swap encryption which is generated at each boot and not stored anywhere.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor It's really systemd/linux, not gnu/linux. The libraries and userland tools aren't relevant here.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `mycommand --key-file <(ansible-vault decrypt)` if your shell supports it? Wouldn't that be the same as writing to `/run`?

Comment: We just need a name to distinguish this Unix (UNIX replacement) that uses Linux, from the kernel that is used on other OSes. Calling the OS Linux, and the kernel Linux is confusing.

Comment: @terdon No, a process substitution would create a pipe. It's useful when you need stdin for something else, but here that's not the problem: either a shell pipeline works or a process substitution doesn't work.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor [Both the OS family and the kernel are called Linux. Deal with it.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4194/but-linux-is-a-kernel/4692#4692) In 99.9% of the cases, including my answer here, there is no ambiguity. If there is some ambiguity, then use an unambiguous name.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' So Android in Linux, and therefore Unix, The same OS as Gnu/Linux? And what about Cygwin, WSL1, and Other OSes that Don't have Linux. Are they Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me this is a really good application of a `fifo`.

You create a `fifo` (using `mkfifo`) that is referenced as a special file, ansible outputs into that file then your commands reads it. Yet it isn't a file, does not touch storage.

As recommended shell "here" files are also good candidates (that `<(CMD)` construct).